# How to add more events to this excel calendar?

Tags: microsoft-excel, calendar

So I downloaded this template for a calendar: https://indzara.com/2019/12/2020-excel-calendar-template/

Calendar with Events

[image]

Settings:

[image]

However, this has a column for events, and highlights it the same colour. Is it possible to add more events columns with different colours? I want different colours since different teams have different events but it needs to be on the same excel sheet, so is it possible to colour code?

Comment: Please replace the website URL with a screenshot of the Excel document you're referring to.

Comment: Look into conditional formatting

Answer (score 0):

Indzara.com seems to offer exactly the feature you are looking for in the premium version of their calendar template. The price seems a bit steep, but looking at the time you'll save compared to modifying and extending the free template's conditional formatting rules - it might just be worth it.